# Page load Conversion tracking through google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I am new to the Google tag Manager.

I want to track the particular page of my website when it's load with the help of google tag manager.

The problem here is that the url of the page is not fixed as I used the dynamic slug in the url.

Help me how to add the tracking for the dynamic url for the page load.

Any blog or video will be very helpful for this issue.

Comment: how the dynamic slug could look like?

Comment: combination of digits and alphabets

Comment: in case if there's no particular template  for  conversion page URL you might track visibility of some  distinct page element like a `<div class="confirmation">Thank you for your order</div>` with visibility trigger (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679410?hl=en)